# How pass parameter and async keyword in lambda method?

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, windows-store-apps, async-await

How can I pass the framworkElement and use an async keyword too in this code?

```
SaveImage = new RelayCommand<FrameworkElement>(frameworkElementForPrint =>  
{
    StorageFile file = await PickImageFileToSave();
    SaveVisualElementToFile(frameworkElementForPrint, file);
});
```

Becaue now the await can not be used...

Comment: Assuming that that type wasn't specifically designed to support `async` lambdas, the answer most likely is "you can't".  (At least not in a meaningful way.  You could make it compile, but it wouldn't work as intended.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend that you factor all your logic into a separate method, as such:

```
public async Task SaveImageAsync(FrameworkElement frameworkElementForPrint)
{
  StorageFile file = await PickImageFileToSaveAsync();
  await SaveVisualElementToFileAsync(frameworkElementForPrint, file);
}
```

Then wrap this into the `RelayCommand`:

```
SaveImage = new RelayCommand<FrameworkElement>(async arg => { await SaveImageAsync(arg); });
```

This separation allows you to unit test your `SaveImageAsync` logic (assuming of course that you refactor with proper abstractions).

[This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn237302.aspx) has a little more detail on `async` commands.

Comment: What's the purpose of this lambda?  Why not write `new RelayCommand<FrameworkElement>(SaveImageAsync)` if you've made the named method?

Comment: The lambda converts the `async Task` into an `async void`. Which of course should be avoided, but in this case (implementing `ICommand.Execute`), it's *logically* an event handler.

Comment: I will try it in a minute, but looks like good. I just cant understand, why not working with two method in lamba, but works with one named method

Comment: @Krekkon Either would work.  Stephen is suggesting this change merely as a matter of best practice, not because this is a requirement.

Comment: I got it, my question is just talk about: in my original example i try write async before frameworkElementForPrint ,but the compiler alarmed me. So i can got it why works this and why doesnt in my example. :))

Comment: By the way i tried this out and its works. Only suggestion is take an async before the Task. :)